# sql: update a table, adding the number of records from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, addition

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio and here is my problem

I have a table1, which contains columns ID (as primary key, all of them distinct) and Sum:

```
ID SUM
--------    
1   10
2   5
3   5
```

Besides this I have a table2, which contains a column ID(not primary key this time, may repeat themselves) and other columns, which are not significant:

```
ID ....
------------    
1
1
2
3
```

What I'm trying to do, is writing a procedure, which updates the SUM from table1 according to the amount of times each id appears in table2, so basically sum for id=1 will be incremened by 2, and for id =2, 3 for each by one

This is what I wrote, trying to update only one record from table1 (and then I would repeat it 3 times for each id):

```
update T1
set T1.sum=T1.sum+
(select count(T2.id) from T2)
from table1 T1
inner join table2 T2 on T2.id=T.id
where T1.id=1 
and T2.id=1
```

but I'm getting an error when I execute the procedure: `Invalid object name 'T2'.`

If I change `T2` to `table2` in here: `(select count(T2.id) from table2)`, I'm getting another error while creating the procedure: `An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.`

What's the deal with my specific attempt, and is there a way to update all 3 rows in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Update T1
Set sum = sum +
    (   Select Count(*) 
        From T2
        Where T2.ID = T1.ID
    )
```